# Linking to specific topics in HelpnDoc compiled CHM using Visual C++ HtmlHelp

Tags: chm, html-help, helpndoc

I am confused here. I have migrated my CHM help from HtmlHelp Workshop to HelpNDoc. I compiled the CHM file and updated my MFC project to direct to the correct topic:

```
HtmlHelp((DWORD_PTR)_T("msa-options-publishers-db.html"), HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC);
```

The above approach worked with my previous CHM file. When I invoke this call the following happens:

[image: CHM]

It doesn't find it. Now I am having difficulties here because if I click F1 in my IDE (VS2017) it takes me to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(HTMLHELP%2FHtmlHelp);k(HtmlHelp);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true). This article provides an example for showing a topic:

```
HWND hwnd =
   HtmlHelp(
            GetDesktopWindow(),
            "c:\\Help.chm::/Intro.htm>Mainwin",
            HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC,
            NULL) ;
```

The above `HtmlHelp` API call is taking 4 parameters. Yet, in my `CDialogEx` derived class I only have two parameters:

[image: HtmlHelp]

So I need to find a way that will work to open any topic in my CHM file as compiled with HelpNDoc.

## Update

On further research I located the topic that discusses the [`HtmlHelp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362kaah4.aspx#CWinApp::HtmlHelp) API call that I am using (found in the `CWinApp` class). It states:

Parameters

> `dwData` Specifies additional data. The value used depends on the value
>   of the nCmd parameter.
>
> `nCmd` Specifies the type of help requested. For a list of possible
>   values and how they affect the dwData parameter, see the uCommand
>   parameter described in About the HTMLHelp API Function in the Windows
>   SDK.

So we end up [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644704(v=vs.85).aspx) where we are given a link to details about `HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC`. We have gone full circle. Looking closely it states:

> Specifies a compiled help (.chm) file, **or** a specific topic within a compiled help file.
>
> To specify a defined window type, insert a greater-than (>) character followed by the name of the window type.

So my code should still be fine.

Comment: Also look at the following for proper HtmlHelp file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851907/not-working-links-in-chm-file-when-start-from-application-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't believe how simple the resolution to this issue was!

I did a test with HTML Help Workship API window:

[image: Test]

The only one that worked was when I used `htm` as the suffix and not `html`. See:

[image: Results]